# Most Visual studio 2013 windows are black and don't show content

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I acquired Visual Studio 2013 with my student status and I've done the installation with the iso that i downloaded. When I launch the software here is what happen :

[image]

When i resize the window, the text can be seen but I can't interact with it, I can't change the thumbnail.

[image]

When i open a script (with Unity), the same thing happen, my code doesn't show up, but when i resize the window i can saw it, but even there, i can't update my code.

[image]

[image]

I've done the installation on another machine and it's working. On mine I've reinstalled/repair over 5 times, the problem is still here. Maybe it have to do with my configuration ?

Comment: In most cases this is an issue with faulty Video drivers. Visual Studio is based on WPF, which uses your video drivers to accelerate the drawing of windows. Faulty drivers can cause all kinds of crazy things to happen. Try downloading and installing the latest drivers for your system, reboot and try again.

Comment: @jessehouwing Thank you for your answer, i'll try to update my GPU's driver, even tough they are up to date.

Comment: @jessehouwing Well it didn't do the trick, i've updated my GPU's driver, the problem is still here.

Comment: Could you provide a little more info on your hardware setup and which versions of Visual Studio you're running? In case you're running a laptop, is it possible that you have a hybrid GPU solution? Mine runs AMD and Intel side-by-side and that causes extra funny behavior.Try forcing Software Rendering to see if that solves it, then at least you know it's a GPU issue. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ddperf/archive/2010/09/16/vs2010-performance-and-bad-video-drivers-hardware-redux.aspx Also try repairing Visual Studio in Programs and Features and re-applying the latest update after that.

Comment: @jessehouwing It did the trick by disabling all three checkbox inside the Visual Experience, i can now navigate and edit my code, thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio uses Hardware Acceleration by default to render many parts of the UI. This can, with some older graphics card or faulty graphics drivers cause issues. The main problem you'll notice is a black screen or parts of the UI that render as a uni-color rectangle.

To see if this is your problem go to the Visual Studio settings and uncheck the following boxes in the settings:

- Automatically adjust visual studio experience based on client performance

  - Enable rich client visual experience
  - Use hardware graphics acceleration if available

[image]

More details about the hardware acceleration features can be found in this old blog post on [vs2010](/questions/tagged/vs2010), it applies to [vs2012](/questions/tagged/vs2012) and [vs2013](/questions/tagged/vs2013) as well.

If turning off these boxes "fixes" your problem at least you can work again :). Now to definitely  fix the problem try uninstalling your current video driver and installing the latest version from your device manufacturer. Making sure you have all the latest service packs for Visual Studio and Windows including hotfixes installed can also help in some cases. If you're running a particularly old version of Windows (say XP or Vista) installing the latest DirectX version may also improve things.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jessehouwing, i've solved this by unckecing all the Visual Experience inside the Options panel, i can now edit my code. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ddperf/archive/2010/09/16/vs2010-performance-and-bad-video-drivers-hardware-redux.aspx

Comment: Your answer, written in it's current state qualifies as a "link only" answer, and because links may break, StackOverflow encourages answers that include a little more information. See my answer for future reference.